# Define an attribute that extends a class in java

Tags: java, android

I have the following class:

```
class Foo {
   public void sayHello(){
       System.out.println("Hello");
   }
}
```

And I want another class to hold a reference to a  class that extends Foo (but can't be Foo). Something like this (erroneous syntax):

```
class Bar {
    private <E extends Foo> E  mFoo;
}
```

Is that possible? how can I do it without declaring it in the class name like this?

```
class Bar <E extends Foo> {
    private  E  mFoo;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can make Foo an abstract class that might solve it if the main point is that E can't be an instance of Foo.  If Foo isn't abstract you could still do

```
public abstract class AbstractFoo extends Foo {
}
```

and then declare E to be of type AbstractFoo.